# How do I debug step to step only through my code? Android studio

Tags: android-studio, debugging

I am trying to do an step to step debug, but then it jump to some root code, like Java.lang and others, that doesn't allow me to debug my code smoothly.

So I should I configure the settings to just debugging only my project when I do step to step debug?

Thank you